# setTimeout() and IE8. Function not being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm searched around Google and even SO, but I can't seem to find a solution here. Case of the Fridays or I'm simply just missing something.

In IE8, this function is not being called. I read that `setTimeout()` is not compatible with IE8 to some degree, but the work-arounds I can't seem to get working with my snippet of code.

Help, what am I missing or doing wrong?

```
onStartup: function () {
    loginForm = $('div#login-box');

    setTimeout(function () {
        loginForm.show();
    }, 1000);
},
```

EDIT: Found issue, this block of code, used for tablet web-apps, was crashing all my js. New question, how do I prevent this function from being run on IE8 - via js.

```
    // prevent default action when
    // moving finger on ipad/iphone
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }, false);
```

Comment: Is your `onStartup` function being executed?

Comment: Do you see any error in console? Is your code reaching inside `onStartUp` function? Is `loginForm` exist and `loginForm.length` is 1 ? I don't think setTimeout is incompatible with IE8 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I've never heard of `setTimeout` having issues in IE8.  How are you calling `onStartup`?  Do you see any errors in the console?  One thing I noticed is you're doing `loginForm =`, not `var loginForm =`.  Maybe `loginForm` is being changed elsewhere?  Where is `loginForm` being declared?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Make sure that your callback is being fired in the first place. If it is, replace `loginForm` with your selector to make sure that it's not a scope issue.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned. No errors, and onStartup() is infact beng called. Works on all other browsers, and IE9+.

Comment: Declare the **variable** with `var`

Comment: @RocketHazmat good eye on the `var`. I'll test that. @blender, let me try without the variable.

Comment: Hmm, function is not being called in IE8. Updating my question with code. Not sure why this works in IE9+ and every other browser.

Comment: Nm, forgot to commit. Def case of the Fridays. :) One sec...

Comment: Okay, there's a bigger problem then initially thought. NONE - ZERO js is working. Note, I'm using Zurb foundation 3 framework.

Comment: Just made an EDIT to my question. Figured out the problem, but created a new one hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't "crashing" the JS - IE8 encountered an error because the `document` object doesn't have the `addEventListener` method in IE8. IE<9 uses `attachEvent`.

Since you're not concerned with touch events in IE8, then you don't even have to run that code, so just put a conditional around it that checks for the existence of the addEventListener method.

Here's how to solve it:

```
// prevent default action when
// moving finger on ipad/iphone
if(document.addEventListener) {
 document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
 }, false);
}
```